# Installation of Osclass On Openshift Cloud Hosting

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, openshift, osclass

i try to install osclass 3.3.x on openshift. i put osclass files at directory" /var/lib/openshift/52cbd62e5973ca1b880000df/app-root/runtime/repo/php" But after filling database name and password it show there is no osclass database.i triple cross check data name, username,password but it is always show this dialog.anyone who already install osclass on openshift please tell what is missing.[image: database set up]

[image: database not here,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host entry is incorrect. OpenShift doesn't use localhost for databases.

Assuming you've already added the MySQL cartridge, you can find out the correct host by sshing into your application and viewing the MySQL related environment variables.

If you have the [OpenShift command line utility](https://www.openshift.com/get-started/#cli) installed, you can do this with the following commands in a terminal:

```
$ cd /path/to/my/app && rhc ssh
```

Then, once you've connected to your application, do

```
\> env | grep MYSQL
```

to see all the MySQL related settings, including the host and the port.

Comment: I think the command should be cd, not ch, but since it's less than 6 characters I can't edit it.

Comment: yes, it should be cd not cd... just a typo on my part ⊙﹏⊙; fixed now.